# (Play Framework 2.3.x) How to get the previous url?

Tags: java, url, playframework, request, playframework-2.3

In play Framework, how can I get the `URL` the user came from in a `controller`?

I've tried `request.url`, but that isn't working.

Comment: you want previous url or current url?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Previous url will come with the http headers under the `referer` key. In JAVA you can get it using:

```
String refererUrl = request().getHeader("referer");
```

and if you doing it in Scala:

```
val refererUrl = request.headers("referer")
```

Comment: Or val refererUrl = request.headers("referer") if you are doing it in Scala

Comment: @ViniciusMiana, feel free to edit the answer to add the Scala version, thx

Comment: It is pretty important that you add `Action.async { implicit request =>` in the action, to get access to the request object.

Comment: or Action { implicit request =>